# What does a manifest's supportedOS setting actually do behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-c++, manifest

I can't find much documentation but recently I had to run the Windows Server 2012 R2 Platform Ready Test Tool to validate some MSVC++ and C# products (.exe's, services, libraries, dll's, etc.) and I came across some error messages saying that the supportedOS setting was not available in some project manifests.

I fixed the errors but I can't help but wonder what the supportedOS setting actually does behind the scenes. For example, say I set the supportedOS setting to Windows 8.1 for all of my projects, will that start to throw errors if running these products on Windows 8 or Windows 7, even though they are known to work for sure on those operating systems?

The most I could find on supportedOS is stuff like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This seems to answer your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I read it again. It just says, "The value of adding GUIDs for both operating systems in the above example is to provide down-level support." So should I just assume that these GUIDs are only used for down-level support? AKA, only a "future" OS version (an OS past the version of the last GUID in the application) will use these GUIDs to provide application compatability support to the OS verison the GUIDs refer to?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - you want to know what happens if the manifest, for example, says that the application *only* supports windows 8 and not any earlier versions, and you try to run it on Windows 7.

Comment: Reading between the lines, my guess is that Windows will not refuse to run the application or warn the user, but will merely give you the default (i.e., Windows Vista) behaviour.  However I can't find a reference that confirms this.  Luckily, we don't really need to know: if you support a particular OS it should be listed in the manifest as supported, and if you don't, it doesn't matter what exactly Windows does - if it runs, it runs, if it doesn't, you never promised it would.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ha, good point! =D I was more worried because of the fact that supportedOS is required for Windows Server 2012 R2 Platform Ready Test Tool validation, so when I added the supportedOS flags into all our apps my manager quickly ran over and asked me if this would cause the app to crash in different OS versions. I figured its only used for compatibility, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: I think the main risk here would be that parts of your application might be expecting the Vista-compatible behaviour.  Adding the supportedOS setting will change the behaviour of the various affected APIs, by turning off the compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo code for how Windows reads the supportedOS values might look something like this:

```
double compatVer = 4.0; // Win95
if (hasW10guid && _WIN_VER >= 0xa00)
  compatVer = 10.0;
else if (hasW81guid && _WIN_VER >= 0x603)
  compatVer = 6.3;
else if (hasW8guid && _WIN_VER >= 0x602)
  compatVer = 6.2;
else if (hasW7guid && _WIN_VER >= 0x601)
  compatVer = 6.1;
else if (hasWVistaguid && _WIN_VER >= 0x601)
  compatVer = 6.0; // Application wants Vista compatibility on Win7+
else if (hasRequestedExecutionLevel)
  compatVer = 6.0; // UAC compatible
```

compatVer is stored somewhere internally in the process, probably in the [PEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block).

compatVer is compared to the real Windows version inside certain functions to either enable new features or change its behavior so it is compatible with the Windows version the application was designed for. Some of the behavior changes are documented in the [compatibility cookbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848074(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Because the supportedOS values are GUIDs they are impossible to guess so developers cannot claim support for Windows versions that have not been released yet. Therefore the Windows 8 GUID will have no effect when the application runs on Windows 7.

There is a risk that your application has a bug that is hidden by compatibility behavior and it might be exposed by adding supportedOS values...

Comment: And before someone asks about the 0x601 Windows version check for the Vista GUID; supportedOS values don't exist on Vista, this manifest section is only used by Windows 7 and later.

Comment: It's not clear for me, what particularly affect a plain .NET app (console, WinForms, WPF) from the MSDN cookbook. Also, may it bring some performance benefits?

Comment: @xmedeko It might have some very minor benefits with DirectX and some kernel functions but the big reason to have them is to be able to detect version 8.1 and 10 because the version APIs will not report anything above 8.0 without them.

Comment: yep, I know, I detect Windows version from the registry now and thinking about switching to `supportedOS` and `Environment.OSVersion`, but worry about the side effects. E.g. our app uses a few things from DirectX. It's a big shame Microsoft does not provide better doc.